# How to implement a React container which can handle all events from its sub-components?

Tags: reactjs, components

Assume that the container contains 3 buttons:

```
<Container>
  <Button1/> <Button2> <Button3/>
</Container>
```

By default, all buttons are in 'Normal' state. If I click on Button1, I'd like to have Button1 becomes 'Active' state (with solid background) and Button2 & Button3 become 'Inactive' state (with gray border).

What's the best way to achieve that in React?

Answer (score 1):

Name is a valid html attribute to use in buttons. If you want to use React to control this, you can simply have a state property attributed to the selected button's name. With that state, you can control the `disabled` attribute, as well as the class name.

```
this.state = {
  activeButton: null
};

onButtonClick = (e) => {
  const { name } = e.target;

  this.setState({
    activeButton: name
  });
};

render() {
  const { activeButton } = this.state;

  return (
    <Component>
      <button 
        className={`${activeButton === 'one' && 'active' || ''}`} 
        onClick={this.onButtonclick}
        name="one"
        disabled={activeButton !== 'one'}>
          Button 1
      </button>
      <button
         className={`${activeButton === 'two' && 'active' || ''}`} 
         onClick={this.onButtonclick}
         name="two"
         disabled={activeButton !== 'two'}>
          Button 2
      </button>
      <button
        className={`${activeButton === 'three' && 'active' || ''}`}  
        onClick={this.onButtonclick}
        name="three"
        disabled={activeButton !== 'one'}>
          Button 2
       </button>
    </Component>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using button as a child component

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setActive = this.setActive.bind(this);
  }

  setActive() {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (<button onClick={this.setActive} className={this.props.active ? 'active' : ''}>
      {this.props.children}
      </button>);
  }
}

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: 0,
    };
    this.buttons = Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((v, index) => index);
    this.setActive = this.setActive.bind(this);
  }

  setActive(active) {
    this.setState({ active })
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      {
        this.buttons.map((value) => (<Button key={value} value={value} active={this.state.active === value} onClick={this.setActive}>Button #{value}</Button>))
      }
    </div>);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-snxy5z)

Make your component look like below, this will work for sure:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.setActiveBackground = this.setActiveBackground.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      selectedCircle: {

     },
    };
  }

  setActiveBackground(name, event) {
     let selected = this.state.selectedCircle;
     selected = {};
     selected[name] = this.state.selectedCircle[name] == "selected" ? "" : "selected";
     this.setState({selectedCircle: selected});
  }


render() {
return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
                <div className="card-panel white">
                  <div className="center">
                    <p>Set Active background in selected button</p>

                    <button onClick={this.setActiveBackground.bind(this, "first")} className={this.state.selectedCircle["first"]}>Button 1</button>
                    <button onClick={this.setActiveBackground.bind(this, "second")} className={this.state.selectedCircle["second"]}>Button 2</button>
                    <button onClick={this.setActiveBackground.bind(this, "third")} className={this.state.selectedCircle["third"]}>Button 3</button>

                  </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
);
  }

}
```

Check demo for output